# Why div are overlapping

Tags: html, css, overlap

I try to put many div's like this.
But something is wrong, all them are overlapped.

I tried to search internet but couldn't find solution.

Any tips to fix it?

Thank you.

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
max-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gamename {
 float: left;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden
}
#gamefps {
 float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="gamename" style="width:30%">PUBG</div>
  <div id="gamefps">85 FPS</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="gamename" style="width:40%">VALORANT</div>
  <div id="gamefps">95 FPS</div>
</div>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="gamename" style="width:50%;">FORTNITE</div>
  <div id="gamefps">110 FPS</div>
</div>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="gamename" style="width:60%; ">APEX LEGENT</div>
  <div id="gamefps">130 FPS</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `position: absolute` in your css and also remove `<br>` from your `html`

```
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative; // Here change absolute with relative
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And in your code, if you've multiple similar elements, its better to use a `class` than an `id`.

```css
.myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gamename {
 float: left;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden
}
.gamefps {
 float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="myProgress">
  <div class="gamename" style="width:30%">PUBG</div>
  <div class="gamefps">85 FPS</div>
</div>
<div class="myProgress">
  <div class="gamename" style="width:40%">VALORANT</div>
  <div class="gamefps">95 FPS</div>
</div>
<div class="myProgress">
  <div class="gamename" style="width:50%;">FORTNITE</div>
  <div class="gamefps">110 FPS</div>
</div>
<div class="myProgress">
  <div class="gamename" style="width:60%; ">APEX LEGENT</div>
  <div class="gamefps">130 FPS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you accept this as answered if it solved your problem, so that your question will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `postion: absolute` and `br` tag in your html code as

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gamename {
 float: left;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden
}
#gamefps {
 float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="gamename" style="width:30%">PUBG</div>
  <div id="gamefps">85 FPS</div>
</div>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="gamename" style="width:40%">VALORANT</div>
  <div id="gamefps">95 FPS</div>
</div>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="gamename" style="width:50%;">FORTNITE</div>
  <div id="gamefps">110 FPS</div>
</div>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="gamename" style="width:60%; ">APEX LEGENT</div>
  <div id="gamefps">130 FPS</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can't use multiple ids with same name in the same document. You must change ids to classes

And `position:absolute` breaks the workflow of the page you must remove that as well.

```css
.myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gamename {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden
}
.gamefps {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="myProgress">
  <div class="gamename" style="width:30%">PUBG</div>
  <div class="gamefps">85 FPS</div>
</div>
<div class="myProgress">
  <div class="gamename" style="width:40%">VALORANT</div>
  <div class="gamefps">95 FPS</div>
</div>
<div class="myProgress">
  <div class="gamename" style="width:50%;">FORTNITE</div>
  <div class="gamefps">110 FPS</div>
</div>
<div class="myProgress">
  <div class="gamename" style="width:60%; ">APEX LEGENT</div>
  <div class="gamefps">130 FPS</div>
</div>
```